# Comparing a specific set of numbers

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that has 6 cells with specific numbers in them.  Every week, a series of numbers is entered in and I would like to flag the numbers in a separate column if they appear for that week.  I was using the formula below where my numbers are in D2->I2 and the weekly ones would be in D18->I18 for example.

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct((D2:I2=D18:I18)))
```

Now, while this works, it's not quite what I'm trying to do.  Unless the numbers match each other exactly, 1 2 3 4 5 6 to 1 2 3 4 5 6 then the addition doesn't happen.  What I would like to have happen is that if, for example, the master column has 1 2 3 4 5 6 and the weekly column has 3 7 9 1 8 5 then the cell with the formula would display the value of 3 for matching three of the numbers that week.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works ?

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(--regexmatch(D2:I2&"", join("|", D18:I18&""))))
```

with exclusion of empty cells in both ranges:

```
=iferror(ArrayFormula(sum(--regexmatch(to_text(filter(D2:I2, len(D2:I2))), "\b("&join("|", to_text(filter(D18:I18, len(D18:I18))))&")\b"))))
```

Comment: Thanks JPV.  That worked, but it seems to work backwards.  If the cells are empty, it gives a value if 6, but if only two out of 6 of the cells contain a value that I am looking to match, then it gives an output of 4.  Thank you.  Paul

Comment: what range should ignore blank cells ?

Comment: It's really close.  The only thing that seems to break is that if the permanent number is 23 for example, putting in either a 2 or a 3 for that week will give a false positive match.

Comment: Okay, I think it works now.  I just needed a space between the quotes/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. but glad to hear you got it working. :-)

Comment: Hi JPV.  I noticed that I am still having an issue.  It is treating each number in the cell as an individual, rather than a whole.  When I put in a 45 it treats it as 4, and 5, rather than 45, so I am still picking up a false positive.  I thought the space would fix it, but it didn't  Any thoughts?

Comment: It does if I switch the cell format from number-> automatic to number-> plain text.  If I leave the cell as number-> automatic, then it still treats any number in the cell as an individual.

Comment: I updated again.. See if this works. If not, please share an example spreadsheet with some data..

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you.